# How to create multiple relationships for multiple foreign keys pointing to the same table?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Let's assume the following two MySQL tables:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Person`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Person` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Parents`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Parents` (
  `person_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `mother` INT NOT NULL ,
  `father` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`) ,
  INDEX `mother_idx` (`mother` ASC) ,
  INDEX `father_fk_idx` (`father` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `person_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`person_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Person` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `mother_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`mother` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Person` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `father_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`father` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Person` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

There are 3 one-to-many relationships between the two tables.

The model classes to be used by SQLAlchemy, can be something similar to:

```
class Person(Base)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)

class Parents(Base)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True)
    mother_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
    father_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

And here are the three `backref` relationships to be added to the `Parents` table:

```
person = relationship(Person, backref=backref('parents', uselist=True))
mother = relationship(Person, backref=backref('mothers', uselist=True))
father = relationship(Person, backref=backref('fathers', uselist=True))
```

Unfortunately, these relationships are not valid; there is no error while creating the tables, but the following appears while trying to insert:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship ...
```

Being very new to SQLAlchemy, I'm having trouble with this situation. Please advice.

[Edit 1]

Small corrections to the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16991346/1237714). The key is to use the `foreign_keys` argument.

Therefore, the relationships can be something similar to:

```
person = relationship(Person, backref=backref('parents', uselist=True), foreign_keys=person_id)
mother = relationship(Person, backref=backref('mothers', uselist=True), foreign_keys=mother_id)
father = relationship(Person, backref=backref('fathers', uselist=True), foreign_keys=father_id)
```

(I've added this as an answer because it is a solution to the problem and it works. I don't know if this is the *right* way to do things in SQLAlchemy, therefore, I'm looking forward to any other answers/alternatives.)